# Render difference between LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX for thick lines

Tags: xetex, luatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}
Foo \xrfill[0pt]{30pt}[black]
\end{document}
```

When rendered by LuaLaTeX, this produces a thick black line with clearly visible vertical stripes:

[image: LuaLateX output]

When rendered by XeLaTeX, the line is solid as expected.

This seemed to come and go at first. I went down several false paths, including the `% !TEX program` string, newlines, LaTeX Workshop vs TexShop, and clearing aux files.

*Edit*: It may be viewer-related. I can see lines in Preview.app and Tex Shop (which may use an embedded Preview pane), but *not* in Chrome. When viewing with Preview, I can consistently toggle stripes/no stripes by building with XeLaTex/LuaLaTex.

Environment: macOS Big Sur 11.2, MacTeX-2020, TeXShop 4.58, all packages up-to-date via TeX Live.

Comment: Hmmm. I see the lines with xetex but not luatex, except in one of my pdf viewers, where the lines show with both. I suspect the viewer.

Comment: @Thérèse Interesting! I have tried a couple of different viewers and will update my question with the results.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the stripes in xpdf but I do in firefox/pdf.js rendering.

`\xrfill` makes a rule out of repeated small adjacent panels, each separately coloured, which is asking a lot of the pdf renderer.  It is simpler to render a single rule with a single colour as in the example below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}
Foo \xrfill[0pt]{30pt}[black]

\bigskip

Foo \textcolor{black}{\leaders\vrule depth 0pt height 30pt \hfill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the actual problem. However, I still see inconsistent rendering between Xe and Lua in the same viewer, which suggests that their output is different enough to change rendering for some viewers. I'd love to report this to the relevant maintainers if it's a real bug.

Comment: @knite I do not think it is a bug in the engines. If you specify adjacent panels you can get rendering artefacts like this, see thousands of comments about vertical or horizontal rules being affected by colortbl coloured backgrounds in any tex forum, that is essentially the same issue.

Comment: The rendering artifacts occur with one engine but not the other - to me this suggests that the engines are doing things differently such that one of them may be "wrong".

Comment: they may be different in fractional rounding differences but how that affects snapping to different pixel boundaries in different viewers depends on the document and which viewer you use, I don't think you can say which one is right and which is wrong (and some pdf viewers are a lot better at avoiding this than others) But feel free to report if you wish, don't let me stop you. (but I have had this issue since I added color support to latex in 1994 and I haven't seen a way to avoid it so far other than avoid writing adjacent panels)